# What does the Dereferenced Field vulnerability in Security Review scan means?

Tags: apex, isv, security-review

I've received a vulnerability from Checkmarx scan that is labelled as `Dereferenced Field` vulnerability.

The scan report message reads like this:

> A possible dereference exist in method uploadDocument. This may lead
> to data exposure.
>
> **Source:**
>
> *File:* MyApexService
>
> *Line:* 651
>
> *Code:* `return MyApexClass.documentUpload(accessToken, cv.VersionData, cv.Title, cv.FileExtension);`
>
> **Destination:**
>
> *File:* MyApexGlobalClass
>
> *Line:* 8
>
> *Code:* `wrapperResponse d = MyApexService.uploadDocument(contentVersionId);`

What does this mean?
How can we resolve or fix this?